# Switching between Gmail accounts allows access to Facebook

Tags: gmail, facebook, google-account

After I logged into my Gmail account from my parents' home PC, where they too use to log into their own Gmail accounts, they are now able to:

- Log into my Facebook account
- View all of my Google search and YouTube history

This is from their workplace computers, even though I've never logged in from there.

These things only happen if they stay logged in Gmail.

I use Google Chrome at home, don't know about the browsers in other places. Is Google sharing information with Facebook? I have Google+ but never use it. I did not accept anything related to these things, only log in, check mails and log out.

Is it possible to end this behaviour somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your parents have enabled synchronization of their workplace Google Chrome with the Home Google Chrome, and all you do at home is synchronized at their workplace too? You can check if a synchronization is enabled by opening a new tab and checking the right top corner - if there is an email written here - it means that the data is being synchronized somehow.